# Shipping a programme with Nuget packages

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, nuget-package

Quick question (and probably a dumb one): I need to install a programme I wrote which uses some Nuget packages and therefore it is almost a GB in size. Nuget created both a "packages" folder and also pasted quite a few `.dll` files into the output dir. If I want to move the programme to another computer, do I need to also provide these `.dll`s and the packages folder?

Comment: `.dll` in the `.\bin` folder: **YES** - the `packages` folder: **NO**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to provide the content of the `packages` folder, but only the DLLs that are necessary for the program to work, which is exactly what NuGet copies to your output directory.

Edit: To clarify, the `packages` folder is only needed when you're developing the program, and if you move to another machine to develop, then that's exactly what NuGet will restore for you, so there's no need to copy the packages in that case either.

Comment: So only move the contents of the bin folder?

Comment: Assuming you meant "move the program" in order to run it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must.
The second possibility is to reinstall the Nuget packages on the new computer.